# How to set the golang server listener available for only my LAN network

Tags: go, server, host, lan

I am using iris platform to do programming in go language (I am very beginner). I want to make all my computers at home be available for accessing to go server which is one of the local machine as well. When I set the listener with my network IP (192.168.0.0) or with any specified IP (192.168.0.15) it gives me panic error back. Only available 0.0.0.0 or 127.0.0.1/localhost or 192.168.0.19 - that is same as localhost

```
import "net"

...

ln, err := net.Listen("tcp4", "192.168.12:9999")
    if err != nil{
        panic(err)
    }

    iris.Serve(ln)

...
```

The error is: **panic: listen tcp4 192.168.0.12:9999: bind: The requested address is not valid in its context.**

Thanks to all for help.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should learn a bit how networks work before start to write servers. You can't bind a listener to IP that is not assigned to the server.

Comment: Yea, I am not very good in networking. But also I am not writing a server, I mean I do, but this is not a goal. I need to build an app in go language that will serve requests. To set the listener you need just put iris.Listen(":9898") line on the end of main method. It will host the service globaly (0.0.0.0:9898). I just want to find out is there any way to restrict external access?  Or may be there is not access from outside of  my LAN?

Comment: Forst I agree with @RomanR. Second if you are using WiFi and you run your go server on your localhost (like your suppose to),  you can access the web server from any device connected to the same WiFi, by visiting the localhost from that machine.

Comment: Thanks lads for help and explanation. Will learn networking.

Answer (score 7):

You should read up on how networking works but here are some points to get you started.

You listen on a port, not an IP address. So whatever machine you're using as your server, find your local IP address:

On Linux or Mac you can do it many ways:

`ifconfig | grep netmask` and get your local address eg. `192.168.x.xx`

Then start up your server with your Go program and listen on a localhost port like 8080.

eg.

```
if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil); err != nil {
    //handle error
}
```

Then you can access the server with other machines in your house assuming they are on the same Wifi. Use a different computer and visit `192.168.x.xx:8080` from a browser.

To answer your question in your comments, outsiders cannot access your local server unless they have a connection to your Wifi.