# "listen tcp (IP):4402: bind: The requested address is not valid in its context" In Golang

Tags: sockets, go, tcp

I use **Socket programming** communication with the **Golang** programming language. I'm using the reference code from this [website](https://www.developer.com/languages/intro-socket-programming-go/), when I run a program that changes the host server's originating IP localhost to the destination device's IP and it gives me an **error message that the requested address is not valid in its context**.

Here is the code for client.

```
// socket-client project main.go
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)
const (
    SERVER_HOST = "192.168.137.178"//IP Server
    SERVER_PORT = "4402"
    SERVER_TYPE = "tcp"
)
...
```

Here is the code for server.

```
// socket-server project main.go
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
)
const (
    SERVER_HOST = "192.168.137.1" //IP Client
    SERVER_PORT = "4402"
    SERVER_TYPE = "tcp"
)
...
```

The error message :
[image: Error message]

Actually the IP did successfully PING and I've seen many answers to the same question but I don't know how to solve it. Anyone, can give me an answer by writing code how to communicate machine via socket programming on Golang ? Thank You.

Comment: Are you sure the 4402 port is open in the server?

Comment: I have activated the port and when I run the program the output is still the same

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to listen on an IP that is not assigned to a network interface on the machine the code is running on. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40697131/11810946).

Comment: But I can FTP to my destination IP, which means I can communicate on the destination IP, So how do I open a port on the Raspberry pi ? I have done several ways but the port is not open either.

Comment: The real purpose of my code is, I want to connect 2 programs with different devices like my PC and Raspberry pi using Socket programming Golang.

Comment: Calling `listen` basically just tells the operating system "if you receive a connection targeting this port then send it to me". Generally you don't specify an IP when listening (e.g. `net.Listen("tcp", ":4402")`); you only really need to specify an IP when your machine has multiple addresses and you only want to listen on one (or listen for local connections only with `127.0.0.1:4402`). If this does not help then edit your question and add more detail (e.g. the IP address(es) of the server) and show how you are calling `Listen`.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely binding the server socket to an address that is not assigned to a local interface in the server host.

Try rewriting your server code like this:

```
server, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":4402")
```

That is, remove the server address from `Listen()` .

Then retry your test.